# Advanced cropping with Python Imaging Library

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, png, crop

I have an A4 png image with some text in it, it's transparent, my question is, how can I crop the image to only have the text, I am aware of cropping in PIL, but if I set it to fixed values, it will not be able to crop another image that has that text in another place. So, how can I do it so it finds where the text, sticker, or any other thing is placed on that big and empty image, and crop it so the thing fits perfectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by extracting the alpha channel and cropping to that. So, if this is your input image:

[image]

Here it is again, smaller and on a chessboard background so you can see its full extent:

[image]

The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image

# Load image
im = Image.open('image.png')

# Extract alpha channel as new Image and get its bounding box
alpha = im.getchannel('A')
bbox  = alpha.getbbox()

# Apply bounding box to original image
res = im.crop(bbox)
res.save('result.png')
```

Here is the result:

[image]

And again on a chessboard pattern so you can see its full extent:

[image]

**Keywords**: Image processing, Python, PIL/Pillow, trim to alpha, crop to alpha, trim to transparency, crop to transparency.

Answer (score -2):

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.png")
im.getbbox()
im2 = im.crop(im.getbbox())
im2.save("result.png")
```