# Python Paste Image without empty space Alpha channel

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm creating a program for Image processing.
For the clarity of the process, I have simplified the code to the maximum:

from PIL import Image

im_layout = Image.open(r"C:\Users\vadym\Desktop\test\Portada-oscura-PNG.png")

im2 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\vadym\Desktop\test\Iphone-XS-Gris-Espacial-1.png")

imres = im2.resize((350, 350))

im_layout.paste(imres,  imres)

im_layout.show()

im_layout.save(r'C:\Users\vadym\Desktop\test\resultado-1.jpg')

This is the result I get:
[image]

This is the result I want:
[image]

The problem is that the pasted image is stored with those empty spaces, I have marked them in red in the last image.

I want to paste just the item in the image, without that empty space.
[image]

Comment: You can trim it first... https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244423/2836621

Comment: Yes, @MarkSetchell, I think that would work. Thank you!! =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question:

im_layout = Image.open(r"C:\Users\vadym\Desktop\test\Portada-oscura-PNG.png")

im2 = Image.open(r"C:\Users\vadym\Desktop\test\Iphone-XS-Gris-Espacial-1.png")

alpha = im2.getchannel('A')

bbox = alpha.getbbox()

cropped = im2.crop(bbox)

imres = cropped.resize((350, 350))

im_layout.paste(imres, imres)

im_layout.show()

im_layout.save(r'C:\Users\vadym\Desktop\test\resultado-1.jpg')

---

thanks to @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 0):

1. remove background of image using any software like adobe, paint 3d
2. crop the image
3. then apply on python

Comment: I need to do it 500 times. Do it Manually is not an option