# How to remove extra transparent pixels from an image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a series of transparent logos.  I paste them on a canvas using PIL. Some of these logos have extra transparent pixels that make the bounding box too wide, like this:

[image]

However, I need these logos and the bounding boxes to be like this:

[image]

How can I remove these extra, unnecessary transparent pixels so the bounding box wraps the logo properly?

Here are some of the logos:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please share representative images, saying which ones are ok and which ones are problematic and also share your code.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The second one is ok, the first one isn't.  What code specifically? At the moment, I don't have any code that removes extra transparency.

Comment: If the image itself already has the extra alpha area, you can crop it using any image editor

Comment: @Halmon Right but I want to do it using Python because I could add 100s of logos to this directory and I can't just manually crop all of them.  I want to programmatically remove the extra transparency..

Comment: How can I trim your logos when you haven't shared your logos - other than merged with some background?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244423/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Check the edit. I added some of the logos..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905421/crop-a-png-image-to-its-minimum-size), you can calculate the bounding box of the non-zero regions (transparent/alpha) and then programmatically crop it.

Snippet from answer:

```
import Image
im = Image.open("test.bmp")
im.size  # (364, 471)
im.getbbox()  # (64, 89, 278, 267)
im2 = im.crop(im.getbbox())
im2.size  # (214, 178)
im2.save("test2.bmp")
```

Comment: When I try to paste the cropped logo (from your code) on the canvas, I get this error: `text_img.paste(new_logo, (logo_position_x, logo_position_y), mask=new_logo)`

Comment: @oo92 Do you have the error that came with your paste code?

Comment: Yea and I diagnosed it. Turns out some of the images are of mode `LA`. I tried to convert them to `logo.convert(mode='RGBA')` but it didn't work