# Converting Image from RGBA to RGB reveals padding, how to crop that?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert an image from RGBA to RGB. But the conversion to RGB is adding padding to the image. How can I convert without the padding? Or how can I remove it?

```
    img = Image.open('path.png')
    img.save("img.png")
    
    rgb_im = img.convert('RGB')
    rgb_im.save("rgb_im.png")
```

Thank you. Images below, before and after conversion:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You aren't showing any images! I can only guess the alpha channel is doing something unexpected. Maybe try cropping to the alpha channel https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244423/2836621

Comment: It's not padding, you're just removing transparency from the frame, so you get it white instead of transparent. You should crop your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open your first image, you'll see that the canvas is larger than the visible image, as you have a transparent frame represented by pixels having `rgba=(255,255,255,0)`. When you remove the `alpha` channel by converting RGBA to RGB, that transparency disappear, as only `rgb=(255,255,255)` remains, which turns out to be the white you see in the second image.

So you want to make something similar to what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616717/5380294)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

def trim_and_convert(im):
    bg = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, (255,255,255,0))
    diff = ImageChops.difference(im, bg)
    diff = ImageChops.add(diff, diff, 2.0, -100)
    bbox = diff.getbbox()
    if bbox:
        return im.crop(bbox).convert('RGB')

im = Image.open("path.png")

rgb_im = trim_and_convert(im)
rgb_im.save("rgb_im.png")
```